# making slideshow autoplay

Tags: html, css

I have created a slideshow using HTML and CSS but need to make it auto play and add controls to it like the pause option.

Here is the code I have.

```
<html>
<style>
span.cap {
display:none;
}
ul.slider {
margin:0 auto;
height:455px;
list-style:none;
position:relative;
width:706px;
}
ul.slider li {
float:left;

-moz-transition: 1s;
-ms-transition: 1s;
-o-transition: 1s;
-webkit-transition: 1s;
transition: 1s;
}
ul.slider li.slides {
border:1px solid #888;
height:453px;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
width:604px;
z-index:10;

-moz-transition: 1s;
-ms-transition: 1s;
-o-transition: 1s;
-webkit-transition: 1s;
transition: 1s;
}
ul.slider li.slides img {
display:block;
left:50%;
opacity:0; 
position:absolute;
top:0;

-moz-transform: scale(0.5);
-ms-transform: scale(0.5);
-o-transform: scale(0.5);
-webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
transform: scale(0.5);

-moz-transition: 1s;
-ms-transition: 1s;
-o-transition: 1s;
-webkit-transition: 1s;
transition: 1s;
}
ul.slider li.slides img.g1,
ul.slider li.slides img.g2,
ul.slider li.slides img.g3,
ul.slider li.slides img.g4,
ul.slider li.slides img.g5 {
margin-left:-302px
}
ul.slider li.lArrow,
ul.slider li.rArrow {
background-color:#bbb;
border:2px solid #888;
height:451px;
position:relative;
width:48px;
z-index:5;
}
ul.slider li.lArrow {
border-radius:100px 0 0 100px;
border-width:2px 0 2px 2px;
}
ul.slider li.rArrow {
border-radius:0 100px 100px 0;
border-width:2px 2px 2px 0;
}
ul.slider li.lArrow a,
ul.slider li.rArrow a {
display:block;
height:100%;
left:0;
position:absolute;
top:0;
width:50px;
}
ul.slider li.lArrow:hover {
background-color:#eee;
left:2px;
}
ul.slider li.rArrow:hover {
background-color:#eee;
left:-2px;
}
ul.slider li.track {
background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
clear:left;
height:25px;
margin-left:51px;
margin-top:-25px;
position:relative;
text-align:center;
width:604px;
z-index:20;
}
ul.slider li.track a {
background-color:#fff;
display:inline-block;
height:15px;
margin:5px;
width:10px;

border-radius:5px;
-moz-box-shadow:2px 1px 1px #000000;
-ms-box-shadow:2px 1px 1px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow:2px 1px 1px #000000);
-o-box-shadow:2px 1px 1px #000000;
box-shadow:2px 1px 1px #000000;
}
ul.slider li.track a:hover {
background-color:#0f0;
}
span#slide1:target ~ ul.slider li.slides .g1,
span#slide2:target ~ ul.slider li.slides .g2,
span#slide3:target ~ ul.slider li.slides .g3,
span#slide4:target ~ ul.slider li.slides .g4,
span#slide5:target ~ ul.slider li.slides .g5 {
opacity:1;

-moz-transform: scale(1);
-ms-transform: scale(1);
-o-transform: scale(1);
-webkit-transform: scale(1);
transform: scale(1);
}
ul.slider li.slides .g0 {
margin-left:-302px;
opacity:1;

-moz-transform: scale(1);
-ms-transform: scale(1);
-o-transform: scale(1);
-webkit-transform: scale(1);
transform: scale(1);
}
span#slide1:target ~ ul.slider li.slides .g0,
span#slide2:target ~ ul.slider li.slides .g0,
#slide3:target ~ ul.slider li.slides .g0,
span#slide4:target ~ ul.slider li.slides .g0,
span#slide5:target ~ ul.slider li.slides .g0 {
opacity:0;

-moz-transform: scale(0);
-ms-transform: scale(0);
-o-transform: scale(0);
-webkit-transform: scale(0);
transform: scale(0);
}
span#slide1:target ~ ul.slider li.track .tr1, 
span#slide2:target ~ ul.slider li.track .tr2, 
span#slide3:target ~ ul.slider li.track .tr3, 
span#slide4:target ~ ul.slider li.track .tr4, 
span#slide5:target ~ ul.slider li.track .tr5 {
background-color:#f00;
}

span#slide1:target ~ ul.slider li.lArrow a,
span#slide1:target ~ ul.slider li.rArrow a {z-index:10}
span#slide1:target ~ ul.slider li.rArrow .a2 {z-index:100}
span#slide1:target ~ ul.slider li.lArrow .a8 {z-index:100}

span#slide2:target ~ ul.slider li.lArrow a,
span#slide2:target ~ ul.slider li.rArrow a {z-index:10}
span#slide2:target ~ ul.slider li.rArrow .a3 {z-index:100}
span#slide2:target ~ ul.slider li.lArrow .a1 {z-index:100}

span#slide3:target ~ ul.slider li.lArrow a,
span#slide3:target ~ ul.slider li.rArrow a {z-index:10}
span#slide3:target ~ ul.slider li.rArrow .a4 {z-index:100}
span#slide3:target ~ ul.slider li.lArrow .a2 {z-index:100}

span#slide4:target ~ ul.slider li.lArrow a,
span#slide4:target ~ ul.slider li.rArrow a {z-index:10}
span#slide4:target ~ ul.slider li.rArrow .a5 {z-index:100}
span#slide4:target ~ ul.slider li.lArrow .a3 {z-index:100}

span#slide5:target ~ ul.slider li.lArrow a,
span#slide5:target ~ ul.slider li.rArrow a {z-index:10}
span#slide5:target ~ ul.slider li.rArrow .a6 {z-index:100}
span#slide5:target ~ ul.slider li.lArrow .a4 {z-index:100}
</style>
```

```
<body>

    <div class="container" id="container">

        <!-- caps, non-existent items -->
        <span id="slide1" class="cap"></span>
        <span id="slide2" class="cap"></span>
        <span id="slide3" class="cap"></span>
        <span id="slide4" class="cap"></span>
        <span id="slide5" class="cap"></span>

        <ul class="slider">
            <!-- left arrow -->
            <li class="lArrow">
                <a href="#slide5" class="a5"></a>
                <a href="#slide4" class="a4"></a>
                <a href="#slide3" class="a3"></a>
                <a href="#slide2" class="a2"></a>
                <a href="#slide1" class="a1"></a>
            </li>
            <!-- slides -->
            <li class="slides">
                <img src="image1.jpg" alt="" class="g0" />
                <img src="image2.jpg" alt="" class="g1" />
                <img src="image2.jpg" alt="" class="g2" />
                <img src="image3.jpg" alt="" class="g3" />
                <img src="image1.jpg" alt="" class="g4" />
                <img src="image2.jpg" alt="" class="g5" />
            </li>
            <!-- right arrow -->
            <li class="rArrow">
                <a href="#slide5" class="a5"></a>
                <a href="#slide4" class="a4"></a>
                <a href="#slide3" class="a3"></a>
                <a href="#slide2" class="a2"></a>
                <a href="#slide1" class="a1"></a>
            </li>
            <!-- tracker -->
            <li class="track">
                <a href="#slide1" class="tr1"></a>
                <a href="#slide2" class="tr2"></a>
                <a href="#slide3" class="tr3"></a>
                <a href="#slide4" class="tr4"></a>
                <a href="#slide5" class="tr5"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a JavaScript file or add this section end of your HTML file.
It's a simple sample:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var i = 0;
var path = new Array();

// LIST OF IMAGES
path[0] = "image_1.gif";
path[1] = "image_2.gif";
path[2] = "image_3.gif";

function swapImage()
{
   document.slide.src = path[i];
   if(i < path.length - 1) i++; else i = 0;
   setTimeout("swapImage()",3000);
}
window.onload=swapImage;
</script>
```

in HTML file every IMG tag should have a src and name attribute like this one:

```
<img height="200" name="slide" src="image_1.gif" width="400" />
```

Try to search in Google. There are a lot of samples.
source: http://www.siteforinfotech.com/2013/07/create-simple-image-slideshow-using-javascript.html

---

Live sample: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vahids/75pggxr4/1/)

Comment: I made the following changes and it still does not work.
Added the script;
<script language="JavaScript">
var i = 0;
var path = new Array();

// LIST OF IMAGES
path[0] = "image1.jpg";
path[1] = "image2.jpg";
path[2] = "image2.jpg";
path[3] = "image3.jpg";
path[4] = "image1.jpg";
path[5] = "image2.jpg";

function swapImage()
{
   document.slide.src = path[i];
   if(i < path.length - 1) i++; else i = 0;
   setTimeout("swapImage()",3000);
}
window.onload=swapImage;
</script>

Comment: <li class="slides">
               <img height="453" name="slide" src="image1.jpg" width="605" alt="" class="g0" />
                <img height="453" name="slide" src="image2.jpg" width="605" alt="" class="g1" />
                <img height="453" name="slide" src="image2.jpg" width="605" alt="" class="g2" />
                <img height="453" name="slide" src="image3.jpg" width="605" alt="" class="g3" />
                <img height="453" name="slide" src="image1.jpg" width="605" alt="" class="g4" />
                <img height="453" name="slide" src="image2.jpg" width="605" alt="" class="g5" />